# Projecting an instance from a A4Solution

Tags: api, alloy

I'm trying to make a new UI to visualize my Alloy instances. I've got an A4Solution and have been successful in extracting atoms, relations, checking atom signatures **BUT** I can't seem to understand how to project the instance on some sig.

I've noticed that I can try to use the edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4viz.AlloyInstance, I've got options to project there, but that'd imply in starting over, from a different angle.

Would that be the way to go? I'd prefer to extract that from the A4Solution object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the `edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4viz.StaticProjector` class and its `project` methods---that's how the Alloy Visualizer implements projections.  If your visualization uses the `edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4viz.AlloyModel` class, you should be able to reuse the existing code in `StaticProjector`; from your post it seems, however, that you'd prefer not use any of the alloy4viz classes, in which case it should not be too difficult to understand how `StaticProjector` works and reapply the same ideas to your project.  Or you could convert an `A4Solution` object to an `AlloyInstance`[1] and build your visualizer around the alloy4viz classes, which, in my opinion, would be a good way to go about your project.

[1] something like:

```
a4sol.writeXML("instance.xml")
AlloyInstance inst = StaticInstanceReader.parseInstance(new File("instance.xml"));
```